# How to convert PEM file to PPK using PuTTYgen in Ubuntu?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, putty, ssh-keys

I have created an EC2 instance on AWS. I want to connect to the instance using PuTTY, but it requires PPK file. I have PEM file which I want to covert into PPK using PuTTYgen.

How do I use PuTTYgen on Ubuntu to convert PEM file to PPK?

I use this command but after exporting key is not working
$ sudo puttygen pemKey.pem -o ppkKey.ppk -O private

Comment: The syntax you specified is correct, what error are you getting?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score -1):

1.install putty-tools:

```
sudo apt-get install putty-tools
```

2.Now convert your .ppk file to .pem using the following command:

```
puttygen key_name.ppk -O private-openssh -o key_name.pem
```

3.Set the proper permission to use the .pem file with following command:

```
chmod 400 key_name.pem
```

4.Connect to you server using the following command

```
ssh -i "key_name.pem" serverusername@server-ip
```

Answer (score -2):

You can download puttygen from this [link](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest.html)

1. You need to download your pemkey.pem from AWS
2. Open PuTTYgen and load on the right side.
3. Set the file type to *.*
4. Open your .pem file in puttygen
5. click "Save private key" and save your ppk key for use with PuTTy